# Can we ignore asking to add host in .ssh directory while executing ansible playbook using python ansible module for a new host?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible, ansible-inventory

Currently, it's asking to enter yes or no which I want to ignore or pass in program itself,

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************
The authenticity of host '192.168.112.188 (192.168.112.188)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:UoKxAB0x6sxQCggsklebbnxhdadajdjvsbbb5w.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

If you want to see the code for ansible can refer the question,

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper' while running playbook using ansible-python module?

Answer (score 2):

You should alter `StrictHostKeyChecking` ssh client option.

There are multiple ways to achieve this. For example, set this in your `ansible.cfg`:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

Comment: It is not asking for authenticity but the ansible is not connecting to host. I am getting host unreachable.

Comment: There are multitude of possible situations when you get 'host unreachable', still `StrictHostKeyChecking` is the answer to your OP.

Comment: You can also set this in ansible.cfg: host_key_checking = False (as described here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#host-key-checking)

Comment: `host_key_checking = False` is much more insecure, than accepting new keys.